# TNS protocol adpter error

Tags: oracle11g, tns

[image]

My oracle password expired , I want to update password but when I am doing sqlplus / as sysdba it giving error. for reference I attached screenshot of error.

Please help me out.

Comment: You should be doing `set ORACLE_SID=noble01`, without the space before the equals sign. Not sure if that's your only issue though. Is the database on your local PC?

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of general error and I think you should check out this steps:

1- Are you sure your oracle service is running?
in services.msc select OracleService and start it.

2- Is there any listener service running on oracle?
you may fi the ORA-12560 by running the oradim utility to create a service for the listener.

if your problem wont resolved do the next steps:

- check $ORACLE_HOME and $PATH variables.
- check your firewall. (stop it to be certain there is no problem)